# mapping from window to document

Tags: html, document, w3c

## HTML5

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#browsers

In general, there is a 1-to-1 mapping from the Window object to the Document object. There are two exceptions. First, a Window can be reused for the presentation of a second Document in the same browsing context, such that the mapping is then 1-to-2. This occurs when a browsing context is navigated from the initial about:blank Document to another, with replacement enabled. ***Second, a Document can end up being reused for several Window objects when the document.open() method is used, such that the mapping is then many-to-1.***

---

As the above second exception,

> Many window objects share one document object by using document.open() method.

My question is "How and when does it happen?"

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Document.open blows the existing contents of the document away, but the document object gets re-used and is assigned a new window object. So both the old window object and the new window object reference the same document object. If you've retained a reference to the old window object in JS, then the document would be accessible through either window object.